# Which soap-based client library can i use for Python 3.5?

Tags: soap, soap-client, python-3.5, suds

I am working in a Python script for updating CI in a uCMDB.
By the moment I have a full script with Python 2.7 and Suds(also cx_Oracle for access to db).
Been searching about Soap clients but don´t know which to use, I´ve seen: suds, zsi, rinse, pysimplesope, SOAPpy. Some abandoned, other with too Little docuementation.
Which do you recommend and why?, preferably available for Python 3.5.

Comment: Tool/framework recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. Also, don't post additional questions as answers (as you've done here).

Comment: `suds-jurko` **is the active friendly fork of suds**.

Answer (score 2):

Give http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/ a try. I'm the author and it's fairly new but it is imho one of the better options available now. I'm also trying to get as much feedback as possible since soap has a lot of edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

[`suds-jurko`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko) is a friendly fork of suds that supports Python 3.

Comment: For any version of Python 3?

Comment: seems to have been officially supporting 3.0 to 3.3; there shouldn't be any incompatible changes from 3.3 to 3.5...

Comment: Do you know if versión 0.7 has been released?